# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'img_files' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am using python 3.6.0b2 on Windows 64-bit.
Below is a python code which trains a `keras` model with images.

```
train_imgs, train_vessels =utils.get_imgs(train_dir, augmentation=True, dataset=dataset,img_size=img_size )
train_vessels=np.expand_dims(train_vessels, axis=3)
n_all_imgs=train_imgs.shape[0]
n_train_imgs=int((1-val_ratio)*n_all_imgs)
train_indices=np.random.choice(n_all_imgs,n_train_imgs,replace=False)
train_batch_fetcher=utils.TrainBatchFetcher(train_imgs[train_indices,...], train_vessels[train_indices,...], batch_size)
val_imgs, val_vessels=train_imgs[np.delete(range(n_all_imgs),train_indices),...], train_vessels[np.delete(range(n_all_imgs),train_indices),...]
# set test dataset
test_imgs, test_vessels, test_masks=utils.get_imgs(test_dir, augmentation=False, img_size=img_size, dataset=dataset, mask=True)

        ##############

def get_imgs(target_dir, augmentation, img_size, dataset, mask=False):

      if dataset=='DRIVE':
          img_files,vessel_files, mask_files = DRIVE_files(target_dir)
      elif dataset=='STARE':
          img_files,vessel_files, mask_files = STARE_files(target_dir)

            # load images    
      fundus_imgs=imagefiles2arrs(img_files)
      vessel_imgs=imagefiles2arrs(vessel_files)/255
      fundus_imgs=pad_imgs(fundus_imgs, img_size)
      vessel_imgs=pad_imgs(vessel_imgs, img_size)
      assert(np.min(vessel_imgs)==0 and np.max(vessel_imgs)==1)
      if mask:
          mask_imgs=imagefiles2arrs(mask_files)/255
          mask_imgs=pad_imgs(mask_imgs, img_size)
          assert(np.min(mask_imgs)==0 and np.max(mask_imgs)==1)
```

---

When I run the above code I get an error. The trace back is given below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "O:\New folder\codes\train - Copy.py", line 89, in <module>
    train_imgs, train_vessels =utils.get_imgs(train_dir, augmentation=True, dataset=dataset,img_size=img_size )
  File "O:\New folder\codes\utils.py", line 314, in get_imgs
    fundus_imgs=imagefiles2arrs(img_files)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'img_files' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

**img_files** will only be available in case of if statements are passed otherwise it will not be bound to a value.

```
      if dataset=='DRIVE':
          img_files,vessel_files, mask_files = DRIVE_files(target_dir)
      elif dataset=='STARE':
          img_files,vessel_files, mask_files = STARE_files(target_dir)
```

if dataset is not DRIVE or STARE then img_files will not have value.

```
fundus_imgs=imagefiles2arrs(img_files)    # img_files has to have some value before you can use it.
```